# Ping different IP addresses and save only ping statistics

Tags: log, ping

I want to ping IP addresses and save only statistics and only the IP address - 0% packet loss

```
$ ping -s 100 -c 5 -i 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 100(128) bytes of data.
72 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 (truncated)
72 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 (truncated)
72 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 (truncated)
72 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 (truncated)
72 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=48 (truncated)
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.869/51.435/51.602/0.348 ms
```

Can I write to log only IP address - 0% packet loss?

Comment: Sorry, what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I have a hunch but I'm not sure what you actually mean. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: @ElderGeek: I think OP wants to filter the output of `ping` in some way and save the filter result to a log file. That would be on topic here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I get that, but again, there is no mention of Ubuntu in the question and every network aware OS I can think of has ping.

Comment: @ElderGeek: Do you believe that the question and its answers would be different on other Linux distributions? Afaik we allow questions about issues that are the same on Ubuntu even if OP uses a different Linux distribution (or even a different Unix).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I believe the question could be [edit]ed to be on topic but IMHO it's not ATM.

Comment: seems on topic to me, but I VTC as unclear

Answer (score 2):

You could simply run that ping command, and then pipe that into `grep 'packet loss'|cut -f 6` This should give you the "0%" part.

I have not tested this and I'm not going into any further details since it is not strictly Ubuntu related. However, the commands I have provided should get you on the right track.

Always remember to do `man <command>` if something doesn't work - that will give you an explanation on how to use it properly.

You may also want to check out `smokeping`. It is a package that monitors latency to certain addresses and then gives you stats and a graph on a web interface. I know it's not exactly what you are asking for, but it could still be an alternate solution to the bigger problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have done so:

grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3})% packet loss'